# Can deleting a Second Hierarchy Public Folder Mailbox cause PFs to stop working?

Tags: exchange-2013, public-folders

A few minutes ago I deleted an empty Public Folder Mailbox (Second Hierarchy).

Suddenly, all Public Folders stopped working and when trying to dropdown public folders in Outlook users received a generic error.

Please note the public folders that stopped working had absolutely nothing to do with the Public Folder Mailbox. THey were in a different mailbox alltogether.

Everything seems to be okay now. After a few minutes the Public Folders came up again.

However, my question remains: Did I do something (potentially) disastrous? Can it be an issue to delete a Second Hierarchy PF mailbox when it is no longer required? I did not expect the sudden drop in all public folders and it had me shaking in my boots when it happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Secondary Mailbox could have been a Hierarchy serving mailbox, if deleted it would reassign a new mailbox after sometime.

if secondary was only Hierarchy serving, and if you deleted it. then the user would not be able access it.

More Details at 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150538(v=exchg.150).aspx